# Is there an algorithm that can approximately search an 'isosurface' of a black box function $f$

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization

Say I have a 2D(dimension can be higher) black box deterministic(no evaluation error) function f, I can evaluate every location's function value by f(x), though f do not have closed form expression.

I wanna 'roughly' search the boundary(i.e. where are the $x$) of f=2 in the space, I see there are some relativie technique called 'iso-surface extraction' but seems more concern on graphics and GPU speaking, while I would concentrate more on the value it self.

My initial thinking was,
start to search a point where f(x)=2 as starting point(easily can be done by nemerical optimization), and then try to search along the isosurface, if the isosurface is a closed set, this search will eventually return to where it starts.

Is there any kind of similar algorithm that is able to tackle this problem?

Comment: Hi @Naofumi, the wikipedia page has some information on [isosurface algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface). I'm not sure if your question may fit better in [scicomp.se].

Comment: The question belongs here if $f$ is measured with error or is a random function.  Otherwise, if $f$ is deterministic, the question likely will be better off in a scientific computing forum.  Naofumi, could you clarify this for us?

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment, the $f$ is a deterministic unkown function (means no noise existing), for instance, a nueral network, a supervise machine learning model.

Comment: This question was recommended while I was typing up a very similar question. I'm interested in $n$-dimensional manifolds however.